# Trying to make this entire line of code into a hyperlink

Tags: php, html

```
echo  <a href = 'test.php'> "CategoryID: " . $row["CategoryID"]. " - Category Name: ".$row["CategoryName"]. </a> "<br>";
```

This is what i have an is not working properly.

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Add-a-Hyperlink-with-HTML From Google search "how to make a hyperlink in html".

Comment: echo  <a href = 'test.php'> "CategoryID: " . $row["CategoryID"]. " - Category Name: ".$row["CategoryName"]. </a> "<br>";

Comment: edit your question http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43282015/edit not in comments please.

Comment: @Jake Add that to the question. If that is the real code there are obvious (the code in the current question doesn't have the errors) syntax errors there.

Comment: `echo <a href` that failed because of no opening quotes and error reporting would have thrown a parse error.

Comment: Use quotes... `echo "<a href = 'test.php'>CategoryID: " . $row["CategoryID"]. " - Category Name: ".$row["CategoryName"]. "</a><br />";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
echo "<a href = 'test.php'>CategoryID: {$row['CategoryID']} - Category Name: {$row['CategoryName']}</a><br />";
```

I am using the `{` and `}` as they allow you to include an array in a string and ignore the concatenation which I find harder to read.

<sub><sub><sub>I find it funny that you can loop through a MySQL array but can't echo a simple string :P</sub></sub></sub>

Some links ([teach a man to fish...](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime)):

- [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_echo.asp)
- [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)
- [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/php)
- [Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_functions.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$link = "";

$link = sprintf("<a href = 'test.php'>CategoryID: %d - Category Name: %s </a><br />", $row['CategoryID'], $row['CategoryName']);

echo $link;

?>
```

Assuming that **$row['CategoryID']** is an integer and **$row['CategoryName']** is a string.